# WooCommerce - change the placement of Attribute on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add an Attribute ("Difficulty") to the main listing of a product page. While I was successful in adding it, I'd like it to be higher and included with the "Category" and "Tags" instead of under the "Add to Cart" button. See screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]

I used the following code (found online), and added it to my functions.php:

```
function njengah_woo_attribute(){
 
    global $product;
    $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
 
    if ( ! $attributes ) {
        return;
    }
 
    $display_result = '';
 
    foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
        if ( $attribute->get_variation() ) {
            continue;
        }
 
        $name = $attribute->get_name();
        if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {
 
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), $name, 'all' );
            $njengahtax = $terms[0]->taxonomy;
            $njengah_object_taxonomy = get_taxonomy($njengahtax);
            if ( isset ($njengah_object_taxonomy->labels->singular_name) ) {
 
                $tax_label = $njengah_object_taxonomy->labels->singular_name;
 
            } elseif ( isset( $njengah_object_taxonomy->label ) ) {
 
                $tax_label = $njengah_object_taxonomy->label;
                if ( 0 === strpos( $tax_label, 'Product ' ) ) {
                    $tax_label = substr( $tax_label, 8 );
                }
            }
 
            $display_result .= $tax_label . ': ';
            $tax_terms = array();
 
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $single_term = esc_html( $term->name );
                array_push( $tax_terms, $single_term );
            }
 
            $display_result .= implode(', ', $tax_terms) .  '<br />';
 
        } else {
 
            $display_result .= $name . ': ';
            $display_result .= esc_html( implode( ', ', $attribute->get_options() ) ) . '<br />';
        }
    }
 
    echo $display_result;
}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'njengah_woo_attribute', 25);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while so probably not needed anymore, but just in case or if someone else wants to do the same. You can do this:

Change:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'njengah_woo_attribute', 25);
```

to

```
add_shortcode( 'difficultyAttribute', 'njengah_woo_attribute');
```

Then you can add the shortcode `[difficultyAttribute]` in the body text wherever you want to place it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'njengah_woo_attribute', 25);
```

to

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'njengah_woo_attribute', 10);
```

The smaller the number at the end, the higher the item will be displayed.

Comment: I just tried that, but no change.